# Измерение уровня шума и добавление его к другому изображению

Tags: c++, opencv

Допустим имеются два разных изображения: одно зашумлено, второе (условно) чистое. Задача состоит в том, чтобы зашумить второе изображение таким же уровнем шума, как и первое изображение.

Первое что нужно сделать, это как-то измерить уровень зашумленности. Для этого я использую `PSNR`. Так как для рассчета `PSNR` нам нужно два изображения (одно не зашумленное), то первое что я делаю, это копирую изображение и устраняю в нем шумы, после чего и высчитываю `PSNR`.

Второе - зашумить изображение. Это я делаю с помощью функции `randn` из `opencv`:

```
cv::Mat addNoise(const cv::Mat &src, double mean, double stdDev) {
  cv::Mat retval;

  cv::Mat noise{src.size(), CV_16SC3};
  cv::randn(noise, cv::Scalar::all(mean), cv::Scalar::all(stdDev));

  cv::Mat converted;
  src.convertTo(converted, CV_16SC3);
  cv::addWeighted(converted, 1., noise, 1., 0., converted);

  converted.convertTo(retval, src.type());
  return retval;
}
```

Для простоты я использую одно значение для всех каналов.

Так вот, вопрос, а как коррелируют значения `stdDev` и `PSNR`?

Comment: Может попробовать измерить шум по другому? Среднее разности цвета в соседних пикселях например.